# What is the first sentence of verse 2:184 literally saying?

Tags: arabic, quran-translation

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

**What is the first sentence of verse 2:184 LITERALLY saying?**

Arabic text is

[image]

Translations we have are

1. "Prescribed number of days" as per Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
2. "Fixed number of days" as per Muhammad Taqi-ud-Din al-Hilali & Muhammad Muhsin Khan
3. "A limited number of days" as per Saheeh International

Although English is not my first language, these phrases, the translators are using, do not give the same meaning according to my understanding. They lead to different interpretation, don't they?

For example, "fixed" means "always the same" whereas "a limited" means "may change but does not exceed limit".

Comment: When different translations use different words, you should probably try to find the common meaning between the words rather than trying to find out where they differ. Fixed and limited number of days both mean "a certain amount of days."

Comment: So if meaning of one translation is what Allah meant and the other is not, then, in order to consolidate differing meanings, one should distort what is meant by Allah?

Comment: @The Z, What is the Arabic text LITERALLY saying?

Comment: The Arabic says a countable amount of days, it also may indicate that the amount is known, because of the passive voice used here.

Comment: Do you mean `known countable amount of days`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word مَعْدُود (or its feminine plural مَعْدُوداتٍ as in this verse) essentially means "counted."

But, the phrase "counted days" doesn't make much sense to an English speaker. He needs to know more and how this would be understood in Arabic.

The word مَعْدُود is used to indicate one of two things:

1. Specified or fixed number. That is because when something is counted, it is specified to a certain amount.
2. Few in number. That is because when something can be counted, that implies it is small. Similar to the word "countable" in English.

Either of these two meanings works in the verse, since Ramadan is only a few days and it is also a specified amount of days.

As for:

> For example, "fixed" means "always the same" whereas "a limited" means "may change but does not exceed limit".

You're reading too much into words. The translators in both instances intended to imply the same thing. Don't take specific English word choice that seriously!

And Allah knows best.

Comment: `fixed number of days` means Shahri Ramadan is always 30 days, as it cannot be always 29. `A limited number of days` means the month canbe 29 days or 30 days and does not exceed 30. `Prescribed number of days` canbe interpreted as the month canbe 29 days or 30 days or even 31 days. The translators may intend to imply the same thing but surely they are not choosing right words to relay what they intend. I don't know you but it seemed an issue to me.

Comment: @Muslim That first one is a terrible interpretation. Why would you even think that? Everyone knows Ramadan changes between 29 and 30 ... Fixed is synonymous with prescribed as you could find in a dictionary. This seems more your lack of understanding English and interpreting words in ways they were not meant

Comment: `Ramadan changes between 29 and 30` this is the problem. According to the Imams of Ahlul Bayt Shahri Ramadan is always 30, not being deficient, ever.